# Negative numbers of bins

Tags: matlab, histogram, bin, negative-number

I have the following code that returns the values of a histogram:\

```
[a,b]=hist(x(:),unique(x));
```

Since I have negative values in `x`, I get for instance the value `-3`, and thus get an error, since the number of bins cannot be negative.

What could be a workaround around this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is size(unique(x))?

Comment: @Dr_Sam. Thanks for your comment. For `-4`, I for instance got `9` values. Do you mean to replace count with the `size`. How could that be made in general since the code will be applied on different images?

Comment: @Dr_Sam. I tried inserting  `length(unique(x))`, and it seems it removes the error. Is it that what you meant? Do you think this change will have any effect on the output? Thanks

Comment: I meant that if size(unique(x))==1 (i.e. all the values are the same), then Matlab does not understand correctly what you want. See the answer from Shai.

Answer (score 2):

the function `hist` can accept a **vecotr** of the center of bins. These centers can be negative.
I think that the issue is when `unique(x)` returns a negative **scalar** then `hist` treats it as the number of bins rather than the bins' centers

workaround

```
ux = unique( x );
if numel( ux ) == 1
   % there is only one unique value in vecor x - 
   % no need to do a histogram, it will only have one bin!
   a = numel( x );
   b = ux;
else
   % many unique values in x - compute a histogram.
   [a, b] = hist(x, ux);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you just kindly clarify what the if-statement really does?